# Does AWS Glue python shell job support Glue version 2.0?

Tags: python, shell, version, aws-glue, jobs

We have Glue job with Type: 'Python Shell', Py version: 'Python 3.6', DPUs: '1/16', Glue version: '1.0'.

How can i change the glue version from 1.0 to 2.0?
Does AWS Glue python shell job even support Glue version 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Python Shell jobs can only run on Glue version 1.0.

Comment: thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

**Python Shell** jobs does not utilize Glue ETL, so that `glue_version` is not a valid parameter for this type of job. You should care about `python_version` instead.